# How to list functions of a python package that are not called inside that package

Tags: python, code-analysis

I'd like to clean up the code in a python package which has some unused class/function definitions. Is there a simple way to list all the functions of a package that are not called within any of the modules of that package? Assume that the 'private' classes/functions (that I want to clean up) are prefixed with an underscore so they are not confused with 'public' API.

Answer (score 2):

Several suggestions:

1. If you are using an IDE like PyCharm, it will gray out the unused
   imports.
2. If you care to install a lint tool like [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/), it will warn
   you of your unused imports.
3. A poor man's way would be to comment out all your import
   statements and see what module invocations complain. You could add them
   back in, one at a time.

Comment: FWIW: I also recommend **pylint**.  It's built into Spyder and very easy to use.  The outputs can be parsed easily with GNU tools, for a bit of customised code analysis.

Comment: If you are using PyCharm, Code -> Organize Inputs will both remove unused imports and arrange them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find *class/functions/vars* usages using **Pycharm IDE** by pressing `Ctrl+LeftMouseButton` on *class/functions/vars* names to search for usages. If no usages where found in your project, simply delete *the dead* code manually.